# Reverse all sub-matrices of a 3D matrix in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a `3x5x5` "matrix" (actually a 3D `numpy.ndarray`). For the sake of some computation that I need to carry out, I must first reverse each subarray of this 3D array, as so:

```
>>> x = np.arange(75).reshape(3, 5, 5)
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],

       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]],

       [[50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
        [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
        [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
        [70, 71, 72, 73, 74]]])

>>> np.array([ np.rot90(k, 2) for k in x ])
array([[[ 24.,  23.,  22.,  21.,  20.],
        [ 19.,  18.,  17.,  16.,  15.],
        [ 14.,  13.,  12.,  11.,  10.],
        [  9.,   8.,   7.,   6.,   5.],
        [  4.,   3.,   2.,   1.,   0.]],

       [[ 49.,  48.,  47.,  46.,  45.],
        [ 44.,  43.,  42.,  41.,  40.],
        [ 39.,  38.,  37.,  36.,  35.],
        [ 34.,  33.,  32.,  31.,  30.],
        [ 29.,  28.,  27.,  26.,  25.]],

       [[ 74.,  73.,  72.,  71.,  70.],
        [ 69.,  68.,  67.,  66.,  65.],
        [ 64.,  63.,  62.,  61.,  60.],
        [ 59.,  58.,  57.,  56.,  55.],
        [ 54.,  53.,  52.,  51.,  50.]]])
```

As you can see, I have found a solution that seemed to work well initially (using `np.rot90`). However, on testing on larger inputs, this method becomes atrociously slow, especially when the first dimension exceeds 100. Is there a faster/more efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse along the `axes 1,2`, thus avoid the loop and hopefully gain some performance boost there. So, the desired output could be simply achieved like so -

```
x[:,::-1,::-1]
```

Comment: Holy cow, what an amazingly simple and elegant solution! Take my vote! Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, how did such a solution strike you? Where did you learn about numpy's indexing tricks? Are there any guides you used that you can refer me to? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @Shiva Well I have been following `numpy` tag on SO for the past one year and trying to learn from the masters here and answering what I could, sorta gives me the practice :) You could do something similar maybe.